# How to derive the speed of an object at P(t) on an ellipse?

Tags: calculus

An object in elliptical motion with the parametric equations: $x(t) = \cos(\pi t)$ and $y(t) = 3\sin(\pi t)$. These parameters form an arbitrary ellipse. We can assume $t$ is non-negative and in units of seconds and values of $x$ and $y$ on the plane are measured in meters. The location of a point at any value of t can be given in $P(t) = (\cos(\pi t), 3\sin(\pi t))$. I understand that there's use of derivation but I'm unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: Differentiate each component

Comment: @JoséAntonio what do you mean by differentiating each component? Do you mean differentiating both x(t) and y(t)? If so, how would that result in getting the speed?

Comment: Pythagorean theorem

Answer (score 1):

The position on the trajectory is described as:
$$\vec{r}(t)=\hat{i}\cos(\pi t)+\hat{j}\cdot 3\sin(\pi t)$$

The velocity derives from position:

$$\vec{v}(t)=\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}=-\hat{i}\pi \sin(\pi t)+\hat{j}\cdot 3 \pi \cos( \pi t)$$

The speed is the magnitude of velocity:
$$|\vec{v}|=\pi \sqrt{\sin^2(\pi t)+9\cos^2(\pi t)}=\pi \sqrt{1+8 \cos^2(\pi t)}$$